# ArcMap 10.2 Create Histogram of Raster Values NOT Color Values

Tags: gis, histogram, raster, arcmap

I'm working on making histograms of pixel values for several rasters to compare them and produce reasonably good graphics. I am using the Spatial analyst toolbar to create a histogram for the rasters but what it gives me is a histogram of the color values in the raster and not the actual pixel values.

[image]

In this image the X axis would ideally show the pixel values from 0 to 3273.

I have tried using zonal histograms and zonal statistics but neither produce a more accurate histogram and using the histogram button on the properties tab (shown below) does not produce anywhere near a useable graphic.

[image]

Comment: You need to ask this on gis.stackexhange.com

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the layer and go to symbology.
it seems you now have a color gradient, but perhaps you want to have a unique color for each value?
that being said, 3700 unique values may be too much to ask.